# Show/hide entity registration form fields depending on registration state

Tags: 7, users, entities

I'm using the [Entity Registration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) on Drupal 7.

I want to show/hide custom fields on the registration form depending on the state of the registration. I thought to use the [Conditional Field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) to solve this, but in the Manage Dependencies tab only my custom fields show up: the state field can't be selected as Dependee.

Why is this and
How to get around it?